# Laravel phpunit skipping custom test files

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have created a laravel test file using the command

> php artisan make:test EventUserRelations

When I run *phpunit*, it is as if the file does not even exist. I tried to fail the test just to make sure it is being tested. Here is the code in the file:

```
class EventUserRelations extends TestCase
{
    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->fail();
    }
}
```

And here is the result.

> phpunit --debug

```
PHPUnit 5.4.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


Starting test 'ExampleTest::testBasicExample'.
.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 119 ms, Memory: 20.75MB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel test files need to end with ..test.php. So change `EventUserRelations.php` to `EventUserRelationsTest.php` and it should work.